# Java virtual method invocation

Tags: java, polymorphism

Say I have the following code:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int salary = 2000;
    public void getDetails() {...}
}

public class Manager extends Employee
{
    public int salary = 5000;
    public int allowance = 8000;
    public void getDetails() {...}
}
```

and a `main()` that does the following:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
Manager man = new Manager();
emp.getDetails(); // method of Employee called, output ok.
man.getDetails(); // method of Manager called, output ok.

Employee emp_new = new Manager();
emp_new.getDetails(); // method of Manager called, ok.
System.out.println(emp_new.allowance); // problem, as Employee doesn't know about allowance. Ok

// the problem
System.out.println(emp_new.salary); // why 2000 and not 5000?
```

The book says "you get the behavior associated with the *object* to which the variable refers at runtime". Ok, I get behavior of Manager class when a *method* `getDetails` is called, but when I access an attribute `salary`, I get behavior of variable and not the object. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no polymorphism of fields. A field in a sub-class hides a field with the same name in the super-class, but if you use a variable of the super-class type - `Employee` - to access the field, you get the field of the super-class.

I don't see the point in declaring fields having the same name in both the super-class and the sub-class. If the sub-class has access to the field of the super-class, it shouldn't declare a field of the same name.

If you must declare a field of the same name in both super-class and sub-class, you can achieve polymorphism by accessing the field via getter and setter methods. You can override the getter and setter methods in the sub-class, so that they access the field of the sub-class instead of the field of the super-class.

```
public class Employee
{
    private int salary = 2000;
    public void getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
}

public class Manager extends Employee
{
    private int salary = 5000;
    @Override
    public void getSalary () {
        return salary;
    }
}

...

Employee emp_new = new Manager();
System.out.println(emp_new.getSalary()); // will print 5000
```

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is because of ***hiding of fields***.

From [JLS 8.3. Field Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)

> If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class.
>
> In this respect, hiding of fields differs from hiding of methods (§8.4.8.3), for there is no distinction drawn between static and non-static fields in field hiding whereas a distinction is drawn between static and non-static methods in method hiding.
>
> **A hidden field can be accessed by using a qualified name (§6.5.6.2) if it is static, or by using a field access expression that contains the keyword super (§15.11.2) or a cast to a superclass type.**

So in your case you are accessing  hidden variable `salary` directly by using reference variable of `Employee` class to store object of `Manager` **(casting to a superclass type)**.

So it will print `Employee` hidden `salary` rather `Employee`class `salary`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Employee` class is the `parent` class and the attributes that are called would return the value of parent attributes (as they have the same name and type).

Answer (score 0):

Because this is NOT `Virtual Method Invocation`.

As quoted:

> you get the behavior associated with the object to which the variable refers at runtime

You overlooked that the variable `salary` IS NOT part of behavior - it is state of Object.